# Itextsharp and adding font to a htmlstring

Tags: c#, itext

I'm having troubles adding font-family to a predefined HTML structure with content in itextsharp.
Whatever I do, it just keep going to the font "Arial".

I can add font-color without trouble.

This is what I'm using:

```
var style = new StyleSheet();
style.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.TABLE, HtmlTags.COLOR, "#00ff00");
style.LoadTagStyle("body", "font-family", "times new roman");

document.Open();

                    List<IElement> sr = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(html), style);

                    foreach (IElement element in sr)
                    {
                        document.Add(element);
                    }
document.close();
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iText[Sharp] HTML/XML parsers only use the [standard PDF Type 1 fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Standard_Type_1_Fonts_.28Standard_14_Fonts.29) by default. [Times New Roman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_Roman#Times_Roman_and_Times_New_Roman) is **not** one of those fonts, so you have to explicitly register it **before** calling `LoadTagStyle()`:

```
FontFactory.RegisterDirectories();
```

or:

```
FontFactory.Register(FULL_PATH_TO_TIMES_NEW_ROMAN);
```

`RegisterDirectories()` registers **all** the Windows system fonts, so it will be much slower.

Or you can go the route of using the Type 1 font, **without** registering extra fonts:

```
style.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.TABLE, HtmlTags.FACE, "times-roman");
```